# Textbox displaying extra information when text file is parsed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**My Goal:** I want to parse a file and display it in a textbox. Here's the code (thanks to Aviral Singh).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"C:\Users\Smith\Desktop\Settings.txt"; //Path to settings file.
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        System.IO.StreamReader sis = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        rtb.Text = sis.ReadToEnd();
        sis.Close();
        foreach (string line in rtb.Lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("Installation Technical Manual:") == true)
            {
                string numbers = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("Installation Technical Manual:"));
                textBox1.Text = numbers;
            }
        }
    }
```

Text file looks like this:
[image]

**My Problem:** The textbox in my program displays entire line: Installation Technical Manual: (1234567890).

[image]

I just want the number with brackets **(1234567890).** to be displayed in the textbox. What changes should I make to the code to remove the words and just display numbers with brackets around it? Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = "(" + new String(numbers.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()) + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `IndexOf()` is going to give you the starting position of the string which you're asking for the index of.  Which in your example is going to be 0, so a `Substring` call that starts at 0 is going to return you the entire string.

What you really want to do is `Substring(IndexOf("Installation Technical Manual:") + "Installation Technical Manual:".Length)`.  That will give you whatever comes *after* your string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ':' in your line always,

```
if(line.Contains(":"))
{
string numbers = line.Split(':')[1];
textBox1.Text = numbers;
}
```

The reason your code is not working as you have used the substring method as with one parameter, so it is used as :

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex
)
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx

And you are passing in, `line.IndexOf("Installation Technical Manual:")`
which will return ).
See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx
So you are essentially saying return `Substring` of `string` Installation Technical Manual:(number) starting at 0 which basically returns the whole line.